# Preventing a spring boot service from failing on startup with Redis not present

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

We have a number of services that use spring boot (v1.2.3) and Spring Data Redis using the spring-boot-starter-redis dependency.

Also we are using spring session and its corresponding redis dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

If the redis server is not started or cannot be reached then the service issues a fail and aborts startup.

Is it possible to allow the service to not fail on startup?  What do I need to setup in order to do so?

**NOTE**: I tracked the critical failure down and it is in the Redis support for Spring Session.  A failure thrown here ripples up to cause the service to failure out.  Is it possible to have a fallback to a regular session if connectivity to redis is failed?

```
RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java at line 156
 public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
     >>>   RedisConnection connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
```

### Stack trace is as follows:

```
2015-06-02 17:20:00.214  WARN 67248 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.services.rpil.MicroServiceApplication.main(MicroServiceApplication.java:47) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:57) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:156) ~[spring-session-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:10) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:133) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) ~[commons-pool2-2.2.jar:2.2]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144) ~[jedis-2.5.2.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Falling back to an embedded Redis instance would defeat the purpose of using Redis to store sessions in the first place.   I would recommend not setting up this sort of behavior.  If you want to run an embedded instance for QA or something like that, use spring profiles to explicitly define which configuration you're using.  That will avoid possible inconsistencies in production.